# How to keep two table's data consistent when deleting records from one of them?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

Say, I have two tables: `students` and `course_scores` .

The attributes in `students` are `student_id, name, sex`;

While the attributes in `course_scores` are `student_id, course, score`.

When I delete the records from `students`, the corresponding records in `course_scores` should also be deleted, right? to make them consistency.

Could you show me the codes to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE course_scores ADD FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES
    students (student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` part is what you want; this will delete all rows in `course_scores` if the corresponding `student_id` is deleted.  Your tables must use the `InnoDB` engine.